# Parse '<' Symbol with lxml

Tags: python, lxml, mathjax

I'm currenlty facing a problem with mathjax equations containing '<' symbols.
If I parse these with lxml the string gets cropped.

Is there a way to tell the parser to not remove unknown tags (I guess thats the problem) but keep them as they are?

E.g

```py
s="<div> This is a text with mathjax like $1<2$, let's see if this works till here $2>1$! </div>"
from lxml import html
tree=html.fragment_fromstring(s)
html.tostring(tree)
```

gives:

```
'<div> This is a text with mathjax like $11$! </div>'
```

It would be fine if the '<' gets escaped an nothing cropped.

I am totally aware that this is not valid xml. But, unfortunately, I cannot replace the '<' symbols with the correct html escaped symbol in the source, because actually, I'm trying to parse a markdown file containing html tags and the < symbol is a perfectly fine symbol here.

Thanks!

Jakob

Comment: because the string is not properly escaped in your XML

Comment: @user2799617 Of course it is not! That's the problem and the reason for the question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lxml alone does not work here, but using BeautifulSoup works fine!

```py
s1="This is a text with mathjax like $1<2$, let's see if this works till here $2>1$!"
import lxml.html.soupparser as sp
from lxml import html  
soup1 = sp.fromstring(s1)
print sp.unescape(html.tostring(soup1, encoding='unicode'))
```

gives

```
<html>This is a text with mathjax like $1<2$, let's see if this works till here $2>1$!</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

If you're using a XML parser to parse something that is not valid XML then you're not using the right tool for the job.

Other solutions would be to either write a custom parser or first pass your markdown content to a markdown engine (cf https://github.com/trentm/python-markdown2 or https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Markdown) to turn it into proper HTML then parse this HTML using lxml's HTML parser (or any other HTML parser FWIW).

Comment: Well, the thing is, I subsequently use pandoc to convert this to latex, and pandoc strips raw html tags (so I cannot use it first) :( But, maybe some other intermediate markdown parser could be applied.

Comment: So you'll have to roll your own solution.

Comment: My initial idea was to get lxml to escape the '<' (if not part of an html tag) like it is doing with e.g. &. This way a simple sub-sequential unescape would be enough.